# connecting to postgresql instance vs a specific database via lua?

Tags: postgresql, lua, postgresql-9.2

I'm not sure if used the right terminology in my question but here's what I'm trying to do. From the command line, I am used to running the following command :

```
psql -U postgres
```

and then I can see a list of all my databases by doing:

```
postgres=# \l
```

I'm wondering how to do the same thing programmatically in lua? 
The following function is what I currently use to connect to a specific db:

```
local db_env, db_con
local connect_db = function()
  if not con then
        db_env = assert (luasql.postgres())
        db_con = assert (db_env:connect(databasename, databaseUser, databasepassword))
  end
end
```

Just wondering how I would change it to connect to the instance of postgresql server to see all the dbs that are hosted by my server.

Thanks.

**Edit 1**

Perhaps when I'm running the command

```
psql -U postgres
```

it is connecting to a default database?

Comment: `SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datistemplate = false;`

Comment: @hjpotter92, I'm asking how to connect, not about how to list the databases once I'm already connected...  Perhaps my question is not clear.  I'll revisit to see if I can improve the way I've asked it. Or maybe there is no way to do what I'm after.

Comment: umm, you could use `os.execute`. I'm still unclear about your question though.

Comment: @hjpotter92 I've tried to clarify my question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you have to connect to the database server and query the server for a list of databases. The database will return a recordset containing a list of the databases on that server.

A great walk-through of connecting to postgres and executing queries ( like the one above that hjpotter92 posted).

[Hitting Postgres From Lua](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/lua/luapostgres.htm)

Hope you find it helpful

Comment: I think they __don't want__ to establish a connection to a specific database at all.

Comment: yes, I guess I was falsely assuming that the command i used on the command line was NOT connecting to a database name, because I wasn't explicitly listing one.  But it is connecting... just connect to the postgres default database.